# How to set a method in route action_type in rest API (api2.xml)?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, amazon-web-services, api-filter

My route section in `api2.xml`

```
 <routes>
                <route_collection>
                    <route>/mymodule/user</route>
                    <action_type>collection</action_type>
                </route_collection>  
                <route_create>
                    <route>/mymodule/user/create</route>
                    <action_type>create</action_type>
                </route_create>     
                <route_update>
                    <route>/mymodule/user/update/:id</route>
                    <action_type>update</action_type>
                </route_update>               
            </routes>
```

My model methods: `mymodule/Model/Api2/User/Rest/Guest/V1.php`

I extend `Mage_Api2_Model_Resource`

```
public function _retrieve() {
    return json_encode(array(0=>'retrieve Function Call done')); 
}

//Collection
public function _retrieveCollection() {
      //Some codes 
   return json_encode(array(0=>'retrieveCollection Function Call done')); 
}

//Create
public function _retrieveCreate() {
     //Some codes
     return json_encode(array(0=>'retrieveCreate Function Call done')); 
}

//Update
public function _retrieveUpdate) {
     //Some codes
     return json_encode(array(0=>'retrieveUpdate Function Call done'));
}
```

I get an error message on API call `magento-host/api/rest/mymodule/user/create`  "code": 405," message": "Resource method not implemented yet."

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you can only have a `route_entity` and a `route_collection` and with those you can have a GET, PUT, POST and DELETE (have a look at http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) and they will match functions called `_retrieve`, `_update`, `_create` and `_delete`. To implement your own REST API methods have a good look at e.g. `api2.xml` in the customer module. So for instance in your own `api2.xml` file you can have:

```
<privileges>
   <admin>
     <create>1<create>
     <update>1</update>
     <retrieve>1</retrieve>
   </admin>
   ....
   <routes>
     <route>/myextension/myproduct/:product_id</route>
        <action_type>collection</action_type>
     </route>
```

Note that I use admin here because a Guest can use only GET. My admin role can now POST (create) and PUT (update) and GET (retrieve).

My code would then look like this:

```
class Mymodule_Myextension_Model_Api2_Myproduct_Rest_Admin_v1 extends Mymodule_Myextension_Model_Api2_Myproduct
{
protected function _update($productData)
{ ... }
protected function _create($productData)
{ ... }
protected function _retrieve($productData)
{ ... }
```

There is a good tutorial on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_extend_magento_rest_api.html

Answer (score 0):

set value `collection` for CREATE action type
and `entity` for UPDATE action type